# assign session value into razor @html.displayfor

Tags: c#, session, razor

currently work on mvc with using razor, where wish to assign my session value to model, may i know how it can be done? did some research but din see any.

to display the ID of student that applying for password recovery, and save the studentId in session in order to further process and show in password recovery form
in view

```
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.StudentId)
            @Html.DisplayFor(m=> m.StudentId)
```

when i wish to assign my session into m.StudentId, is there anyway can solve it?

in controller

```
Session["StudentId"] = passwordrecovery.StudentId;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, the best way would probably be to create a viewmodel, to which you assign the StudentId in your action before you return the view, rather than keeping the value in the session. You then pass the viewmodel to the view, and will have access to the StudentId in your view when creating your form.

```
// Create a view model that fit your needs
public class PasswordRecoveryViewModel {
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    // Other properties as needed
}

// Do something like this in your action
public ActionResult YourAction () {
    var model = new PasswordRecoveryViewModel {
        StudentId = 1; // Assign the ID as needed
    }    
    return View(model);
}
```

Then at the top of your view you add this:

```
@Model YourNameSpace.PasswordRecoveryViewModel;
```

You will then have access to your student ID with `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.StudentId)`

Comment: yea i did create viewmodel, please let me know if my concept is either bad practice or not, for the viewmodel i create such as student, which contain studentid, password, email, and etc. is it require for me to create each model such as logonmodel, passwordrecoverymodel, and etc but most of them contain same attributes.. having problems during change view(password recovery) where validate id and email and wish to pass the id to another view(setnewpassword) and display the id and let user key in the new password with using student model.. really thanks for your explain..

Comment: wow thanks for enlighten me with the    var model = new PasswordRecoveryViewModel {
        StudentId = "1"; // Assign the ID as needed
    }

Comment: i believe i could just assign the studentid with session.. thanks you very much

Answer (score 1):

you do not need to store the id in session. use the built-in membership provider functions to manage the user account.

beyond that I would recommend loading anything/everything you need for the view into the viewbag and not rely on other external sources for data. this can be done using ActionFilters to pull values out of sources (like Sesssion) and place them into the ViewBag or View Model.

Comment: thanks for ur reply, currently having some doubt *so sorry is the membership only apply on users table for built in database? quite newbie to this.. because i create my on table for student and staff, so not very sure is it possible to use membership provider functions to amange my custom student and staff table.

Comment: research the universal membership provider. you should be able to adapt your model to the provider to provide your own implementation without the need for membership specific tables.

Comment: thanks to @jason Meckley guidelines.. thanks for your help :)